# ¿Como arranco otro sistema operativo?

Tags: linux, io

tal vez no venga mucho al caso esto, pero si me pueden ayudar seria de mucha ayuda ya que no se donde mas buscar...
Resulta que mi docente nos paso un programa ADIOS.iso que esta en mi pendrive ahora, este programa es una maquina virtual un sistema de operativo que trabaja con Linux... mi duda es para hacerlo funcionar solo debo de entrar al boot menu y arrancarlo directo o necesito algo mas...
o en todo caso tengo DVD's en blanco... no manejo archivos.iso asi que no se si solo debo copiarlo al DVD y luego arrancarlo desde ahi... o necesito hacer algo antes para poder hacerlo funcionar. Acabo de tomar taller de sistemas operativos asi que soy nuevo en esto, se que para mucha gente debe de ser sencillo es por eso que pido su ayuda...

Comment: Es un disco virtual(Que corre en una maquina virtual) o el .iso del sistema operativo ? son dos vainas diferentes... uno necesitas instalar una maquina virtual como VirtualBox para correr el sistema, y el otro quemarlo en un CD o una memoria Booteable e instalarlo en un disco real... das muy poca información, porque ni tu sabes en si que es.

Comment: Si lo lamento... se que no me doy a entender bien, nos dijo que este archivo.iso nos lo copiaramos supongo que de ahi tengo que quemarlo a un dvd... ya que el usaba uno para arrancar desde ahi el sistema, pero no se precisamente como hacer eso si solo tengo que quemar el programa, es la primera vez que veo estas cosas y por eso ando perdido

Comment: Si es la iso del Sistema operativo, es quemarlo en un CD o utilizar una memoria booteable y pasar a realizar la instalación de este en un disco duro, el linux para quemar CD esta el programa brasero o K3b.

Si es un disco virtual, necesitas tener instalado un virtualizador como VirtualBox o el que sea de tu elección.

Answer (score 2):

Según entiendo te proporcionaron una imagen de linux .iso, como no explicaste lo que te solicito tu profesor te indico que puedes hacer 2 cosas con la imagen:

1. Quemar la imagen en un CD/DVD o memoria USB para la instalación en una maquina física, sea por particiones o directamente como sistema operativo único. Para ello debes crear una unidad de almacenamiento Booteable (CD/DVD o USB) para ello utilizo [LinuxLive](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/).
2. (Mi Recomendación) Utilizar la imagen para su instalación en una Maquina Virtual ([VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), [VMWare](https://www.vmware.com/), etc). Personalmente te recomiendo esta opción ya que es una forma de trabajar con diferentes sistemas operativos de una forma mas cómoda.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, es un programa ADIOS.iso en ese caso instalo VirtualBox y con ello debo de instalarlo?

Comment: Si correcto utiliza virtualbox